# How do I find the link to share a Raw Google Form (where you can edit questions)?

Tags: google-forms

In the add-collaborator dialog in Google Forms there's a setting "General access - Anyone on the internet with the link". Below that setting, I find a button that gives me a link to the Google Form that can be filled out but not be edited.

In Google Docs and Sheet I can easily find the link that I can give to collaborators.

I can't find the link in Google Form that I can give collaborators. Where is that link?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the correct link already. The problem is that the default access role `Viewer`, and *viewers* get automatically redirected to the fill-out version of the form when they access the edit link. You need to give them edit access.

In the **File > Share > Share with others** dialog box, grant `Editor` access to the form to `Anyone with the link`.

Comment: I want people to be able to access the form without me needing to know their email addresses to invite them.

Comment: Grant `Editor` access to "anyone with the link."